# Scala/Play: Create a Future[ List[ ... ] ] from a (partial) List[ ... ]

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a List of things, lets just say Strings.
I want to transform that into a Future[ List[ ] ] of things, lets again say Strings.
Parallel execution is **not** wanted.

This will end up in an Action.async, so blocking is not welcome.

I have a handler that may transform an element in the future.
Simplified to this:

```
def handle( input: String ): Future[ String ] =
{
  input match {
    case "X" => Future.failed( new Exception( "failed on "+input ) )
    case other => Future.successful( "handled "+other )
  }
}
```

In the end I want to return a Future[ List[ ... ] ] including the first failed result and then stopping.
Could be simplified to this:

```
  def handleInOrder( inputs: List[ String ] ): Future[ List[ String ] ] = {
    val output = new ListBuffer[ String ]( )
    breakable { for( input <- inputs ){
      Await.ready( handle( input ), Duration.Inf ).value.get match {
        case Success( result ) => output += result;
        case Failure( reason ) => output += "Ex:"+reason; break
      }
    } }

    Future.successful( output.toList )
  }
```

The order in which things are handled is important.

This works as is, but I really want to get rid of that "**Await.ready**".

I hope my question is clear, at the moment I just cannot wrap my head around this.

A call of

```
handleInOrder( List( "a", "b", "X", "c" )
```

should return

```
List(handled a, handled b, Ex:java.lang.Exception: failed on X)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foldLeft` to execute the `Future`s in sequence.

```
def handleInOrder(inputs: List[String]): Future[List[String]] = {
    inputs.foldLeft(Future.successful(ListBuffer.empty[String])) { case (acc, next) => 
        handle(next).recover { case t: Throwable => "Ex: " + t.getMessage}
            .flatMap(f => acc.map(_ += f))            
    }.map(_.toList)
}
```

This will `recover` all failed `Future`s from `handle`, replacing the them with successful ones containing the exception message. If you want to entire `Future[List[String]]` to fail on one bad input, you can remove `recover` from the chain.

Comment: This is very close, but I actually want the processing to stop after the first failure. (While still providing the results up to that point!)

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise handling your success-or-failure with an `Either` (or scalaz `\/`), and reserving `Future.failure` for unexpected failures, in the same way that many people advise not to use exceptions for "normal" control flow. Then your return value can have a sensible type, rather than being a `List` that randomly contains both `String`s and `Throwable`s.

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.Future, scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global //or your own execution context

case class MyError(input: String)

def handle( input: String ): Future[ MyError \/ String ] =
  input match {
    case "X" => MyError(input).left
    case other => Future.successful( ("handled "+other).right )
  }

def handleInOrder(inputs: List[String]): Future[(List[String], MyError) \/ List[String]] = 
  inputs.foldLeftM(List().right: (List[String], MyError) \/ List[String]) {
    (acc, input) => acc match {
      case -\/(alreadyFailed) => Future.successful(-\/(alreadyFailed))
      case \/-(successfulSoFar) =>
        handle(input) map {
          case \/-(alsoSuccessful) => \/-(alsoSuccessful :: successfulSoFar)
          case -\/(nowFailed) => -\/((successfulSoFar, nowFailed))
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You are obviously right. In the actual code I do exactly that (Right( result ), Left( error ), Failure( critical )). I just oversimplified when reducing it for the sample above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will stop on the first fail:

```
def handleInOrder(inputs: List[String]): Future[List[String]] = {
  def run(inputs: List[String], output: ListBuffer[String]): Future[ListBuffer[String]] = inputs match {
    case h :: t => handle(h).flatMap{x => run(t, output += x)}.recover{ case t: Throwable => output += ("Ex: " + t.getMessage)}
    case _ => Future { output }
  }
  run(inputs, ListBuffer.empty[String]).map(_.toList)
}
```